# php carbon interpret as years instead of hours

Tags: php, php-carbon

I just realized that

```
new Carbon('2018');
```

Results in the current date with the time 20:18

Is there some way to tell carbon to interpret it as years without specifying the exact format?

i.e.

```
new Carbon('May 2018');
```

should be 2018-05-01

and

```
new Carbon('2018');
```

should be 2018-01-01

Comment: try with `Carbon::create(2018)`

Comment: @kip ok, that's better. Does not produce 2018-01-01, but at least 2018-06-08 (so it is the year plus current month, date). Works for 2017 as well. I just wonder why new Carbon and Carbon::create work differently

Comment: Because `new Carbon` is `new DateTime` and `Carbon::create` is `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Comment: @kip unfortunately, create does not accept input like 'May 2018'

Comment: I've re-tagged your question because you used [tag:carbon] but that 's for an [application-development framework for MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/carbon/info).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the first of the year, use `createFromDate`

```
Carbon::createFromDate(2018, 1, 1);
```